# Why the "sample1@gmail.com" goes to the next line? Even though i only display:block the span?

Tags: html, css, responsive, display, web-frontend

## HTML

```
<div class="contact_info">
  <ul>
  <li><h2>Call Us: </h2><span><a href="tel:12345678"><mark>1-234-5678</mark></a></span></li>
  <li><h2>Email: </h2><a href="mailto:sample1@gmail.com">sample1@gmail.com</a><span>Business Email: <a  href="mailto:sample2@gmail.com">mailto:sample2@gmail.com</a></span></li>
<li><h2>Visit Us: </h2><span><address>123 Maple Avenue, Suite Alpha, California 12345</address></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.contact_info {margin: 45px 0 0;}
    .contact_info ul {display: flex;justify-content: space-between;}
    .contact_info ul li {text-align: left; font-size: 17px;}
    .contact_info ul li span{display: block;}
    .contact_info ul li a {color: #333;display: inline;}
    .contact_info ul li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
    .contact_info ul li:first-child h2 {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500;}
    .contact_info ul li:last-child h2 {font-size: 20px;}
```

Why the sample1@gmail.com goes to another line? Even though i only display:block the span?

Comment: What did you want to happen when you use the h2, which is normally used for some sort of heading, on a line of it’s own.

Comment: Thanks brother, i did not know heading's behaves like that, but I want to target them because they have an individual font-size as you can see last 2 lines on my css

Comment: That's a terrible reason for using any heading. Use a div or span with a class if you just want an element to style.

Comment: The best HTML to use for this is a definition list `<dl>`. You can `display: inline;` elements that are initially block-level objects to get them to display inline, or use Flexbox or some other technique to make children appear one next to another.